# The tooltip for the "New contributor" is buggy if the answer is grayed out due to negative score

Tags: bug, design, new-contributor-indicator

If an answer is grayed out due to having enough negative score, the tooltip for the "new contributor" will be displayed incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: Reproducible in Firefox Nightly 80.0a1. [Example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62951975/4642212).

Comment: Also repro'd on Chrome 84, Windows 10. Kind of reminded me of the issue with instantaneous/fade-in animation on spoiler block back then.